# Creating a collapse comment area

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello there and thank for reading this post.

I'm trying to realize the following, as the title suggested, I have a post and would like to display a comment box (sliding down) upon clicking the comment button using JQUERY and BOOTSTRAP.

So far I have this: (jquery and html)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.frenMeta span.clickable').on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            // expand the panel
            $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $(this).removeClass('panel-collapsed');
        }
        else {
            // collapse the panel
            $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $(this).addClass('panel-collapsed');
        }
    });
});

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col col-sm-9 col-centered">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="pull-left"><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" class="img-circle">&nbsp;Post Title goes here</h4>
                <h5 class="pull-right">48 points · 9h</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed dolor at velit ultricies porta. Mauris vehicula in arcu eget pulvinar. Phasellus vel condimentum purus. Cras luctus nisi eu neque aliquet, eget laoreet tellus rhoncus. Donec laoreet sed...</p>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <p class="text-center frenMeta" style="margin: 0px;">Rate this post <a href="#" class="rate"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="rate" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;Comments <span class="badge">3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-xs clickable">Reply <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;·&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="fren.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-xs">Read more <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></p>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="panel panel-default panel-collapsed">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form center-block">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control input-lg" autofocus="" placeholder="What do you want to share?"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Post</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/of4j0xfr/1/

But right now the only thing happening is the first panel is collapsing and not the comment panel.

Also, any idea on how to collapse the comment panel by default?
I've tried: "panel-collapsed" but it's not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: how did you call a "comment button"?

Comment: it's a clickable span

Comment: did you wish somethin like this?: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cnwsc6m/2/)

Comment: its not span .. use inspect element to see the html in browser

Comment: @Banzay, Thanks very much.
It's almost what I want, the only problem is, I have lots of posts and commentArea in a page, so the comment panel cannot be has an id. It must have a class and I have to get only the first one after the giving post.

Comment: uhmmm... I updated  it to class. check it now the same link

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you very much.
Can you post an answer so I can accept it.
Would you happen to know why it's not collapse by default?
I've added: "panel-collapsed" to the comment section and it's now working.

Comment: Actually I just notice that you simply changed the id for a class in the jquery, so now all the comments open and close at the same time. This is why I needed to catch the first comment after the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a panel-comment class to the element you were trying to hide and added display: none; to .panel-collapsed.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.frenMeta span.clickable').on("click", function (e) {
    if ($('.panel-comment').hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
        // expand the panel
        $('.panel-comment').slideDown();
        $('.panel-comment').removeClass('panel-collapsed');
    }
    else {
        // collapse the panel
        $('.panel-comment').slideUp();
        $('.panel-comment').addClass('panel-collapsed');
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/of4j0xfr/2/

Hope it is what you are looking for.

**EDIT:** If you have multiple posts on one page may I suggest you put each post in a wrapper and use the first parent of that class to select the right element. Otherwise all .panel-comments will open.